# How to get my list to be able to be used in another function and across files?

Tags: python, list, function

I am working on a project for school and I have finished almost all of the assignment except I can not get a list to be able to be used for another function whenever my professor made it mandatory to have a list in one function and use it in the others as mandatories when the function is called. I will include below the function I am having trouble with while also including my main file in case I messed up there.

Here is the functions that require the list called 'board'.

```
from characterGen import Player
import random


def CreateBoard(height, width):
    board = []
    for i in range(height):
        board.append([])
        for j in range(width):
            board.append(".")
    return board


def PlacePlayer(board, Player, height, width):
    row = random.randint(0, len.board)
    column = random.randint(0, (len.board[0]))
    Player["row"] = row
    Player["column"] = column
    board[row][column] = "@"

    return board, Player


def ShowBoard(board):
    for height in board:
        print(" ".join(height))
```

Here is the main loop.

```
from my_utilities import *
from consoleClear import *
from characterGen import Player, GenPlayer
from boardGen import *

def Main():
    while True:
        GenPlayer(5)
        choice = input("Would you like a new character?(y/n): ").upper()
        if choice == 'Y':
            Player.clear
            clear()
        elif choice == 'N':
            break
    height = int(input("\n\nHeight: "))
    width = int(input("Width: "))
    CreateBoard(height, width)
    PlacePlayer(board, Player, height, width)
    ShowBoard(board)
Main()
```

It gives this error whenever I run either.

PlacePlayer(board, Player, height, width)
NameError: name 'board' is not defined

What I want it to do is to draw a board of '.' with the player being represented as a '@'. Any help will be greatly appreciated,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the values returned from the functions, you need to store them:

```
board = CreateBoard(height, width)
board, Player = PlacePlayer(board, Player, height, width)
ShowBoard(board)
```

Answer (score 1):

Its evident from error the cause itself. The variable `board` is not defined.
Change this portion

```
CreateBoard(height, width)
```

to

```
board = CreateBoard(height, width)
```